# Calculate pearson correlation between a tensor and a numpy array

Tags: dataframe, numpy, tensor, pearson-correlation

I have managed to form a Dataframe of the predicted tensors(y_pred) which are of (459,1) after reshaping from (459,1,1) and i have the original y values in the other column which are also float32.
[image]

I would like to measure the pearson correlation between this 2 columns. but i am getting error:

```
pearsonr(df_pred['y_pred'],df_pred['y'])
```

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'tuple'

So i am not sure whether i can convert the tensor to numpy array and add that to the DataFrame. I have tried

```
predicted= tf.reshape(predicted, [459, 1])
predicted.numpy()
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
predicted =predicted.numpy()
```

The above code worked at the end. As the values were appended under a for loop only writing

```
predicted.numpy()
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to evaluate each tensor in the column to get it's value.

```
df['y_pred'] = df['y_pred'].apply(lambda x: x.eval())
```

[How to get the value of a tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927890/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-tensor-python)